# 7zip exclude files that are in the folder

Tags: linux, centos, 7-zip, centos-7

```
$ /usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html ᐅ 
.
├── image
│   ├── cache
│   │   └── catalog
│   │       ├──cart.png
│   │       ├── demo
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       └── logo.png
│   └── catalog
│       ├── cart.png
│       ├── demo
│       ├── index.html
│       └── logo.png
└── system
    └── storage
        ├── cache
        └── modification
```

You need to exclude the file in the folder

```
/usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/cache/*
/usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/system/storage/cache/*
/usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/system/storage/modification/*
```

This is not how

```
7za a /usr/local/lsws/poly/back_up/3.7z /usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html -axr!/usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/cache/* -axr!/usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/system/storage/cache/* -axr!/usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/system/storage/modification/*;
```

Error

```
zsh: event not found: /usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/cache/
```

My Program

- CentOS 7
- p7zip Version 16.02
- zsh

Comment: In Bash the `!` is used to retrieve the history. You have to escape it or put it in single quotes: `'-axr!/usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/cache/'*`. If the `*` is used for Bash file expansion, it should be kept outside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong switch. [`-ax`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/ar_exclude.htm):

> -ax (Exclude archive filenames) switch
>
> Specifies archives to be excluded from the operation.
>
> Multiple exclude archive switches are supported.

What you probably want is [`-x`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/exclude.htm):

> -x (Exclude filenames) switch
>
> Specifies which filenames or wildcarded names must be excluded from the operation.
>
> Multiple exclude switches are supported.

Comment: 7za a -mx9 /usr/local/lsws/poly/back_up/`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`.7z /usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html -x!/usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/cache/*; zsh: event not found: /usr/local/lsws/poly/public_html/image/cache/

Comment: You might have to escape the `!`.